add and view cart with django session
def add_cart(request, pk):
    produit = Produit.objects.get(id=pk)
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity', 1))  # Get the quantity from the form
    cart = request.session.get('cart', [])
    
    if quantity > produit.quantitéP:
        messages.error(request, "La quantité dépasse le stock!!")
        return redirect(reverse('details-produit', args=[produit.id]))
     
    # Append the product and its quantity to the cart as a dictionary
    cart.append({'produit_id': produit.id, 'quantity': quantity})
    
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    messages.success(request, "Produit ajouté au panier avec succès ")
    return redirect('cart')

def view_cart(request):
    cart = request.session.get('cart', [])

    produits_in_cart = []
    for item in cart:
        produit_id = item.get('produit_id')
        quantity = item.get('quantity')

        try:
            produit = Produit.objects.get(id=produit_id)
            produits_in_cart.append((produit, quantity))  
        except Produit.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    return render(request, 'app1/cart.html', {'produits_in_cart': produits_in_cart})


I'm trying to add a product and his quantity into a cart after that i wanted tho show all the products with their quantity in a cart template but i'm getting and (AttributeError at /cart
'int' object has no attribute 'get') Error
here's my views :
